# Find rows with foreign key references to non-existing records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called "boxes" with a primary key of "id". I have another table called "books" with a primary key of "id" and a foreign key of "box_id", referencing the box to which it belongs. A book can belong to no box (a "box_id" of null) or a box that doesn't exist. I want to find all books that belong to either no box or a box that doesn't currently exist. Here's the query that I have so far, which seems to work:

```
SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
  WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM "boxes" WHERE "boxes"."id" = "books"."box_id"))
```

Sample in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bde6c/1). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Query looks fine, other than the extra/unneeded parentheses around the entire `WHERE` clause.  What is your question here?

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this query?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on your query, but I expect it is already using an index on `id` from the `boxes` table.

Comment: From the SO Meta FAQ: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) Please provide sample data for both tables and the resulting output you expect to obtain from that data.

Comment: @KenWhite I edited the question to provide a link to sqlfiddle for the sample data.

Comment: Nope. The details of the question need to be here, in the question  itself, so that it's available for future users. See the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Doesn't the inner SELECT need fields or *? I have never seen quote marks delimiting table and field names.

Comment: @June7: Postgres allows a SELECT with an empty column list. And double quotes are defined by the SQL standard for quoting identifiers (although they are not needed here)

Comment: "*A book can belong to no box (a "box_id" of null) or a box that doesn't exist*" - that's a situation that a foreign would prevent in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A foreign key constraint on PostgreSQL will still allow a null foreign key. However, it won't allow it to reference a non-existing record. So a book can still belong to no box, but it can't belong to a box that doesn't exist.